# Unable to push a docker image to the docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

This is the image I'm trying to push to the docker hub

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
smiduthu/has_test   latest              2e0d0ba5412a        27 minutes ago      765.4 MB
```

I'm doing `docker push smiduthu/has_test`.

The following error is occured while I try to push the image

```
The push refers to a repository [smiduthu/has_test] (len: 1)
2e0d0ba5412a: Image push failed
FATA[0002] Error pushing to registry: token auth attempt for registry https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: https://auth.docker.io/
=repository%3Asmiduthu%2Fhas_test%3Apull%2Cpush&service=registry.docker.io request failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: did you begin with `docker login` in order to be logged? Can you post `docker info` and `docker version`

Comment: Yeah, I logged in.
`docker info`

`Containers: 2
Images: 108
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 112
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 4.0.3-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.6.2 (TCL 5.4); master : 4534e65 - Wed May 13 21:24:28 UTC 2015
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 1.957 GiB
Name: boot2docker
ID: JOUQ:AHEU:WWGP:GNR5:7RPM:X76N:JA27:4ETB:V7EL:GVIG:HKIW:2NNU
Debug mode (server): true
Debug mode (client): false
Fds: 26
Goroutines: 47
System Time: Wed Jun 17 08:54:29 UTC 2015
EventsListeners: 0`

Comment: `Init SHA1: 7f9c6798b022e64f04d2aff8c75cbf38a2779493
Init Path: /usr/local/bin/docker
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Username: smiduthu
Registry: [https://index.docker.io/v1/]`

Comment: docker version

`Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64`